# Symfony doctrine convert from db to Entity comments are missing

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm using this official [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) to generate `entityies` from `database`, all works well except db column comments they are totally missing.

When i run this mapping import command in xml i see column comment

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

right after running

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

when i open `Entity/SomeTable.php` `some_column` (which had comment in database) dose not have options={"comment":"some comment"} in annotation

So do i miss some option for `convert` command or it is bug of `doctrine/symfony` and is there a solution for this ?

*Note: i have tested this with both symfony2 and symfony3 issue is same*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @SimeonKolev answer i was able to implement simple fix for this issue in **doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php** to have `options={"comment"=".."}` filled in each Entity

**Solution was** add in `EntityGenerator.php` method `generateFieldMappingPropertyDocBlock` before `if (isset($fieldMapping['unsigned']) ...` condition near to `~1652` line

```
if( isset($fieldMapping['options']) && is_array($fieldMapping['options']) 
    && isset($fieldMapping['options']['comment']) ){

    $column[] = 'options={"comment"="'.$fieldMapping['options']['comment'].'"}';
}
```

Comment: Very nice, see if you can manage to propose a PR against the doctrine bundle repo.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no option that will convert your comments and add it to the entity class. The Entity geneartion can be seen in the **DoctrineBundle** of Symfony in the class **Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator** this class says it all:

> Generic class used to generate PHP5 entity classes from ClassMetadataInfo instances.

So in easy words the mapping you create in xml is then read as **ClassMetadataInfo** and the **EntityGenerator** generates the entity class from that **ClassMetadataInfo**. If you want you can try to add an implementation for the comment or propose a PR or bug in the symfony git repository.

See **generateFieldMappingPropertyDocBlock** method of the **Doctrine\ORM\Tools\EntityGenerator** class and see if you can manage to understand the code and add your comment from there.